# Can the page that shows Sonos Credentials allow copy?

Tags: sonos

The page on the Sonos developer site that shows credentials used does not allow selection of the Key or Secret in the browser, which makes it impossible to Copy to the clipboard. I have to resort to View Source and get it that way, which is excessive.

Comment: We have found an issue where firefox doesn't allow selection. We're working on a fix. In the meantime, can you try another browser (assuming you're using firefox)?

Comment: I tired Firefox and Edge, same problem in both.

Comment: Ok. I’ll add Edge to the list of problem browsers. Can you try Chrome and see how that works?

Comment: Sorry no, I don't let Chrome near any of my computers.